# find and findone giving me model contents instead of records

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch one record from Mongo using the following code.

I have created a schema in another file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const appData = require('../../../core/utilities/appData.js');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const clientListingSchema = new Schema({
...});
const clientListingsModel = mongoose.model('clientlistings', clientListingSchema);
module.exports = clientListingsModel;
```

And have imported the above in another file

```
const clientListingModel = require('./../models/clientListing');
clientListingModel.findOne({'_id': client_listings_id}).then((client_listing) => {
console.log(client_listing);
});
```

But I am getting something like this

```
model {
  '$__': InternalCache {
    strictMode: true,
    selected: {},
    shardval: undefined,
    saveError: undefined,
    validationError: undefined,
    adhocPaths: undefined,
    removing: undefined,
    inserting: undefined,
    version: undefined,
    getters: {},
    _id: 5dd4de69c7d3b8585464dadd,
    populate: undefined,
    populated: undefined,
    wasPopulated: false,
    scope: undefined,
    activePaths: StateMachine {
      paths: [Object],
      states: [Object],
      stateNames: [Array]
    },
    pathsToScopes: {},
    ownerDocument: undefined,
    fullPath: undefined,
    emitter: EventEmitter {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
      _maxListeners: 0
    },
    '$options': true
  },
  isNew: false,
  errors: undefined,
  _doc: {
    number: 3,
    hub_coordinates: [
      0,
      0,
      toBSON: [Function: toBSON],
      _atomics: {},
      _parent: [Circular],
      _cast: [Function: _cast],
      _markModified: [Function: _markModified],
      _registerAtomic: [Function: _registerAtomic],
      '$__getAtomics': [Function: $__getAtomics],
      hasAtomics: [Function: hasAtomics],
      _mapCast: [Function: _mapCast],
      push: [Function: push],
      nonAtomicPush: [Function: nonAtomicPush],
      '$pop': [Function: $pop],
      pop: [Function: pop],
      '$shift': [Function: $shift],
      shift: [Function: shift],
      pull: [Function: pull],
      splice: [Function: splice],
      unshift: [Function: unshift],
      sort: [Function: sort],
      addToSet: [Function: addToSet],
      set: [Function: set],
      toObject: [Function: toObject],
      inspect: [Function: inspect],
      indexOf: [Function: indexOf],
      remove: [Function: pull],
      _path: 'hub_coordinates',
      isMongooseArray: true,
      validators: [],
      _schema: [SchemaArray]
    ],
   ...
  },
  '$init': true
}
```

Need help figuring out how I can get only the record and not model contents.

Any help figuring this out is appreciated.

Comment: Use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(client_listing))`

Comment: @Subburaj  That works. Add it as an answer. Actually till now haven't been using JSON.stringify , and it has still been working.

Comment: Glad to help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)** 
By default, Mongoose queries return an instance of the Mongoose Document class. Documents are much heavier than vanilla JavaScript objects, because they have a lot of internal state for change tracking. 
Enabling the **lean** option tells Mongoose to skip instantiating a full Mongoose document and just give you the POJO.

change your code as below

```
clientListingModel.findOne({'_id':  client_listings_id}).lean().then((client_listing) => {}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try for the following:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(client_listing))
```